# BANDWIDTH SHARING SCHEMES IN PLATFORM CONTROLLER HUB

Tags: io, cpu-architecture, bandwidth, peripherals, memory-bandwidth

What are the possible schemes for sharing the bandwidth of the link between the Platform Controller Hub and the CPU?

How could concurrent transfers work say for two I/O devices attempting to use DMA  capabilities?

Are there arbitration schemes to ensure fair use of the PCH to CPU link?

Comment: Are you talking about real hardware from some vendor, or hypothetical designs?  You're assuming a system where the memory controllers are built-in to the CPU, right?  (I'm assuming from the use of PCH rather than northbridge / southbridge.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes. I'm asking from a hypothetical viewpoint. It does not need to Platform Controller Hub specific.

Comment: I have to brush on this but basically, PCIe devices should have ACKs lines. So only after being acknowledged they can transmit. The Root Complex will ACK only one device of the one requesting to transmit. The choosing algorithm can take a QoS into account, be FIFO o simply unfair.